# How to add multiple columns in COZYROC lookup plus result Column

Tags: ssis

LOOKUP PLUS

In the Lookup definition, We have input Column,Reference result Column,no Null and No Match .

How can we add multiple number of columns into Result column.

In result column i need to add multiple columns from my table.

how can i get this?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used that component a lot, but it appears that you can just add a second row:

If your row is:

```
Input column   :   Reference    :  Result column   : On NULL : No Match

    ID             lkpID           Desc              0         0
```

add another row by starting to type into the row with an '*' to bring in an additional column like so:

```
    ID             lkpID           CodeValue         0         0
```